# Which right square pyramids are scissors congruent to a cube?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, discrete-geometry, scissors-congruence

Consider a right square pyramid whose base has side length $2r$ and whose height is $h$. Let the dihedral angle between the base and each triangular side be $\theta$, and the dihedral angle between adjacent triangular sides be $\phi$. We have $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2 + h^2}}$$ and $$\cos(\phi)=\frac{-r^2}{r^2+h^2}$$ so in particular $$\cos^2(\theta)=-\cos(\phi).$$

This square pyramid is scissors congruent to a cube iff its Dehn invariant is zero, for which it is necessary that $\pi$ be expressible as a rational linear combination of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

If $r=h$ then this condition is satisfied, and indeed such a square pyramid is scissors congruent to a cube. There is no other nontrivial way to satisfy this condition with both $\theta$ and $\phi$ being rational multiples of $\pi$, as shown by [this answer on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3338539/49965).

It seems unlikely that there are any other solutions at all, but I have no idea how to even begin to prove such a thing. To ask a precise

> **Question**: Are there any pairs $\theta$, $\phi$ such that $\cos^2(\theta)=\cos(\phi)$ and $\pi$ is expressible as a rational linear combination of $\theta$ and $\phi$, except where $\cos(\phi)\in\{0,\frac12,1\}$?
>
> Equivalently, are there any pairs $\theta$, $\phi$ such that $\cos^2(\theta)=\cos(\phi)$, and $\pi$ is expressible as a rational linear combination of $\theta$ and $\phi$, but $\theta$ and $\phi$ are not rational multiples of $\pi$.

---

**Added later**: I asked the question above in the expectation that the answer would be no, which would then imply the nonexistence of other right square pyramids that are scissors congruent to a cube. Unfortunately it is quite easy to see that the answer is actually yes, as Daniil Rudenko points out below.

This shows that I asked the wrong precise question. The right question is more complicated, and is described – and answered – by user145307.

Comment: Nitpicking : I think that for interior angles, $\phi>\pi/2$, and accordingly $\cos(\phi)=-r^2/(r^2+h^2)=-\cos^2(\theta)$.

Comment: @BS Fair point! I’ve edited the question accordingly.

Comment: A remark: it is easy to see that a right square pyramid is scissor congruence to a Shlafli orthoscheme.

Comment: I asked a similar question to yours about arbitrary tetrahedron.

Comment: So... you say that "The right question is ... answered by user145307" and then you don't accept the answer. Keeping it classy, MO!

Comment: Sorry @user145307, I intended no slight to your wonderful answer! I usually wait a few days before accepting an answer, in case someone finds a problem or posts another good answer. I’ve accepted yours now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not the question you want to ask. (The actual question asked is easy by a continuity argument.) If the sides of the pyramid have length $2r$ and the height is $h$, then the other side lengths of the pyramid have length $\sqrt{2r^2 + h^2}$. You want to ask whether the element

$$\xi = (2r \otimes \theta) + (\sqrt{h^2 + 2 r^2} \otimes \phi)$$

is trivial in the Dehn group. For this to be true, either:

1. $\theta$ and $\phi$ are both rational multiples of $\pi$ (case already done).
2. $r$ is a rational multiple $0 < v < 1/\sqrt{2}$ of $\sqrt{h^2 + 2 r^2}$, and so

$$\xi = \sqrt{h^2 + 2 r^2}  \otimes (2 v \theta +  \phi);$$

then one moreover demands $2 v \theta +  \phi$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$. This is a much more stringent requirement.
In fact, it never happens, by the following elementary but tedious argument.

By scaling, we can assume that $h = 1$. Hence it follows that $r^2$ is a rational multiple of $1 + 2 r^2$, which certainly implies that $r^2$ is rational. So let $r^2 = t$. Thus we require that

$$\frac{r}{\sqrt{1 + 2 r^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{t}{1 + 2 t}} = v$$

is rational. It follows that we have
$$r^2 = t = \frac{v^2}{1 - 2 v^2}$$
for some rational $v$. Thus we can rephrase the problem as follows:

> Find all rational $0 < v < 1/\sqrt{2}$ with
>   $$\cos(\theta) = \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2 + 1}} = \frac{v}{\sqrt{1 - v^2}},$$
>   $$\cos(\phi) = \frac{-r^2}{r^2 + 1} = \frac{-v^2}{1 - v^2},$$
>   and such that
>   $$(2 v \theta + \phi) \in {\mathbf{Q}} \pi.$$

Let us do an example to explain how one can eliminate any specific $v$.
Take the case of $v = 1/2$. We find that
 $$\cos(\theta) = 1/\sqrt{3}, \quad \cos(\phi) = -1/3,$$
 from which we deduce (for example) that
 $$\cos(2 v \theta + \phi) = \cos(\theta + \phi) = - \frac{5}{3 \sqrt{3}}.$$
 If $\alpha = 2v \theta + \phi$ is a multiple of $\pi$, then
 $$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{\zeta + \zeta^{-1}}{2},$$
 where $\zeta = e^{i \alpha}$ is a root of unity. But knowing $\cos(\alpha)$ one can
 solve for $\zeta$ and then determine if it is a root of unity or not from its minimal polynomial.
 In the example above, we win immediately
 because $2 \cos(\alpha)$ should be an algebraic integer and it is not.
 The cases $v = 1/3$ and $v = 2/5$ can be handled in a very similar way: if $v = 1/3$, then $\cos(\theta) = 1/(2 \sqrt{2})$ and $\cos(\phi) = -1/8$, and,
 with $\alpha = 3 (2v \theta + \phi)$,
 $$\cos(\alpha) = \cos(2 \theta + 3 \phi) = \frac{87}{256},$$
 and if $v = 3/5$, then $\cos(\theta) = 3/5$ and $\cos(\phi) =9/25$, and
  with $\alpha = 5  (2v \theta + \phi)$,
 $$\cos(\alpha) = \cos(6 \theta + 5 \phi) = \frac{3617721}{4194304}.$$
 In both cases, the corresponding $\zeta$ is manifestly not a root of unity because $2 \cos(\alpha)$
 is not an algebraic integer.

Returning to the original problem,
the first thing we will do is prove that ${\mathbf{Q}}(e^{2 v i \theta})$ is an abelian extension.
We may write
$$e^{2 v i \theta} = e^{(2 v  \theta  + \phi) i}  \cdot e^{- \phi i}.$$
Since $2 v \theta + \phi \in {\mathbf{Q}} \pi$, the first factor is a root of unity and so lies in an
abelian extension. On the other hand, the second term is simply
$$\cos(\phi) - i \cdot \sin(\phi).$$
Since $\cos(\phi) \in {\mathbf{Q}}$, it follows that $i \cdot \sin(\phi) = \sqrt{\cos^2(\phi) - 1}$ lives 
in an imaginary quadratic extension of ${\mathbf{Q}}$. In particular,
$e^{- i \phi}$ clearly lies inside an abelian extension. Taken together, we deduce:

> The extension ${\mathbf{Q}}(e^{2 v i \theta})$ is abelian.

We also have the explicit formulae
$$e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta) =  \frac{v + i \sqrt{1 - 2 v^2}}{\sqrt{1 - v^2}},$$
and then squaring:
$$e^{2 i \theta} =   \frac{ 3 v^2 - 1 + 2 v  \sqrt{2 v^2 - 1}}{1 - v^2}.$$

Let $v = a/b$ with $(a,b) = 1$,  this becomes
$$e^{2 i \theta} =   \frac{ 3 a^2 - b^2 + 2 a \sqrt{2 a^2 - b^2 }}{(b^2 - a^2)}.$$
Let $E = {\mathbf{Q}}(\sqrt{2 a^2 - b^2 })$, which is an imaginary
quadratic extension of ${\mathbf{Q}}$. (The condition that $a/b = v < 1/\sqrt{2}$
implies that  $b^2 > 2 a^2$.)
Let us write
$$x = 3 a^2 - b^2 + 2 a \sqrt{2 a^2 - b^2 } \in \mathcal{O}_E.$$
Note that $N(x) = (b^2 - a^2)^2$.
Secondly, note that
$$e^{2 v i \theta} = (e^{2 i a\theta})^{1/b}$$

By Galois theory, $E(\alpha^{1/b})$
can only be an abelian extension of ${\mathbf{Q}}$ (or even of $E$) under the following conditions:

1. $\alpha$ is a perfect $b$th power in $E$.
2. $b$ is even and $\alpha$ is a perfect $b/2$th power in $E$.

(Added explanation: You can work prime by prime on the divisors $p$ of $b$.  Suppose that $\alpha$ is not a perfect $p$th power for a prime $p > 3$. Then the Galois closure of $E(\alpha^{1/p})$ is $E(\alpha^{1/p},\zeta_p)$ and contains the automorphism $\tau: \alpha^{1/p} \rightarrow \zeta_p \alpha^{1/p}$. But then Galois group of $E(\zeta_p)$ over $E$ contains an element $\sigma$ which fixes $\alpha$ and sends $\zeta_p$ to $\zeta^i_p \ne \zeta_p$. Then $\tau$ and $\sigma$ do not commute. The same argument works if $p = 3$ as long as $E(\zeta_p) \ne E$, which can only happen if $E = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$. But $2 a^2 - b^2 \ne - 3 c^2$ by $3$-adic considerations. The same argument works for "$p = 4$" as well, as long as $E(\zeta_4) \ne E$, which can only happen if $E = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$. But $2 a^2 - b^2 = - c^2$ can't happen when $b$ is even (which is the only relevant case) because then $a$ is odd and $2 a^2 - b^2$ is $2 \mod 4$.)

Moreover, since$(a,b) = 1$, if $e^{2 i a \theta}$ is a perfect $b$ or $b/2$th power, then so is $e^{2 i \theta}$.
In particular, $e^{4 i \theta}$ is a $b$th power in $E$. Note also that
$$e^{4 i \theta} = \frac{x^2}{N(x)} = \frac{x^2}{x \overline{x}} = \frac{x}{\overline{x}},$$
so $x/\overline{x}$
is a perfect $b$th power in $E$.
Our goal is now to prove that the ideal $(x)$ is (almost) a $b$th power,
and deduce that $N(x) = (b^2 - a^2)^2$ is (almost) a $b$th power.

Suppose that $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_E$ which divides both $x$ and $\overline{x}$.
I claim that $\mathfrak{p}$ divides $2$. Note that $N(x) = (b^2 - a^2)^2$, so 
so $a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod \mathfrak{p}$.
But then
$$x + \overline{x} = 2(3 a^2 - b^2) \equiv 4 a^2 \mod \mathfrak{p}.$$
If $a \in \mathfrak{p}$ then also $b \in \mathfrak{p}$ contradicting that $(a,b) = 1$. Hence $(x,\overline{x})$
is only divisible by primes above $2$. 
Since $x/\overline{x}$ is a $b$th power, and 
 $(x,\overline{x})$ is supported at primes above $2$, we deduce that $(x) = I^b  \cdot J$
where $J$ is supported at primes above $2$. We deduce that

> $$N(x)  = (b^2 - a^2)^2 = n^b \cdot 2^k.$$

where $n$ is an odd integer. Let us first consider the case when $a$ and $b$ are not both odd.
In this case $k$ is trivial, and $(b^2 - a^2)^2 = n^b$. Since $b^2 - a^2 = 1$ has no solutions
in positive integers, it follows that $b^2 - a^2 > 1$, but then
$$b^4 > (b^2 - a^2)^2 \ge 2^b,$$
from which we deduce that $b < 16$.
Now suppose that $a$ and $b$ are both odd. Since $(b-a,a+b) = 2$ in this case,
it must be the case that
$$b-a = r^b 2^u, b+a =  s^b 2^v,$$
where one of $u$ and $v$ must be equal to $1$.

1. Case 1: $u = 1$. If $b-a=2$, then from the inequality
   $v < 1/\sqrt{2}$ and $a < b/\sqrt{2}$, we deduce that 
   $$2 = b - a > b(1 - 1/\sqrt{2}),$$
   and thus $b < 7$. If $b-a=2 \cdot r^b$ with $r > 1$, then
   $$b \ge b - a \ge 2^{b+1},$$
   which is impossible.
2. Case 2: $v = 1$. We have $a+b = 2 \cdot s^b$, and now
   $$2b > a + b \ge 2^{b+1},$$
   which once again is impossible.

Putting this together, we deduce that $b < 16$.
Checking all the cases with $b < 16$
(noting that $a/b < 1/\sqrt{2}$ and $(a,b) = 1$) we find that the only possible pairs
are 
$$(a,b) =  (1,2), (1,3), (3,5), \ \text{or} \ v =1/2, 1/3, 3/5.$$
But these cases have already been considered previously.

Comment: Impressive answer, a real "proof from The Book"... Welcome to MO !  May I ask details (reference/name) for the Galois theory result that $E(\alpha^{1/b})$ abelian implies $\alpha$ (almost) perfect $b$-th power in $E$ ? This is not (by far) my area of expertise... As a tiny optimisation, note you can obtain $b<8$ instead of $16$ using $n\geq 3$.

Comment: Dear anonymous user145307,
A colleague of mine Guillaume Duval, a french mathematician, recently solved the problem about the pyramids with trivial Dhen invariant. He followed the same paths than you. However, there is a missing point in your very nice exposition, which concern the abelinanity of the Kummer extension of $X^b-\alpha$ in the case when $b$ is even. He managed to overpass nicely this difficulty but this was the step that most cost him in this story.
Can you please contact us (guillaume.duval@insa-rouen.fr) for a possible collaboration and exchange of informations?
best regards

Answer (score 7):

I am afraid I am missing something, but let me try nonetheless. 
Take $\phi=\theta+r\pi$ for any rational $r\in(0,\frac{1}{2}).$ We are trying to 
find a solution of the equation $$f(\theta)=\cos^2(\theta)+\cos(\theta+r\pi)=0.$$
Clearly, $f(0)>0,$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{2})<0,$ so  it has a solution.

Comment: Ha! I feel rather embarrassed I didn’t seriously consider the possibility that there *are* solutions. Sadly I fear this shows only that I asked the wrong precise question, since this is not a *sufficient* condition for the Dehn invariant to be zero.

Comment: No problem! That just makes it more interesting.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the condition "Dehn invariant is zero" does not imply that $\theta,$  $\phi$ are rationally dependent. And indeed, understanding when $$2r \otimes \theta +\sqrt{h^2+2r^2} \otimes \phi$$ vanishes seems like a hard problem.

Comment: Indeed this amounts (if my calculations are right) to find positive integers $m,n$ such that with $x=2n/m$, $x^2>2$ and $a(x)^{2m}=b(x)^{2n}$ for $a(x)=(1-i\sqrt{x^2-2})/\sqrt{x^2-1}$ and $b(x)=(1-ix\sqrt{x^2-2})/(x^2-1)$ (complex numbers of modulus $1$). These equations take place in the imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{x^2-2})$, hence in a cyclotomic one, and one can use automorphisms of the latter to derive more... Or maybe elliptic curves with complex multiplication ?

Comment: I should add that $\tan(\theta)=\sqrt{x^2-2}$, and should have said "this equation takes place".

Comment: @DaniilRudenko if the Dehn invariant is zero then $\pi$ is expressible as a rational linear combination of $\theta$ and $\phi$; but not conversely in general.

Comment: @RobinHouston I don’t see, why: the lengths of the edges are not equal to each other

Comment: @RobinHouston Oh, sorry, you are right.